# Passing data through ViewControllers with Storyboard

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, storyboard

I have two view controllers with a `UITextField` on the SecondVC that I want to push data back into a `UILabel` in the first viewController.
The first ViewController is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

`prepareForSegue`?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use a block property.

Expose a block property on the SecondVC that takes an `NSString`:

```c
@property (copy, nonatomic) void ^TextFieldBlock(NSString *textString);
```

Set this property in `prepareForSegue` in the first view controller and update your `UILabel` inside the block (use weakSelf to avoid retain cycle issues):

```c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    [segue.destinationViewController setTextFieldBlock:^(NSString *textString) {
        weakSelf.mainLabel.text = textString;
    }];
}
```

Then invoke the block property in the SecondVC and pass in the `UITextField`'s text when it returns:

```c
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self TextFieldBlock](textField.text);
    return YES;
}
```